# Shibboleth with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, shibboleth

My client is using shibboleth for other software systems ( eg. Library service, photocopying facilities, study material databases ). He wants my web  application also be configured with shibboleth so that a single identity can be used throughout the system for a user. 
I am new to Shibboleth. I don't know how to start. what are the steps needed to fit it in my application (asp.net , vb ). i have read the docs provided by shibboleth. but don't know the starting steps.

Comment: Is Shibboleth using Windows Active Directory auth?

Comment: its using the database

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nothing about Shibboleth, but I would do the following: first check if Shibboleth provides any authentication APIs. If yes, integrate with them, otherwise integrate with Shibboleth database directly and implement customized authentication for ASP.NET application.